# How to transpose data with many columns in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose, proc

Hi I new in SAS and I have a problem. I have the data which contains 337 rows and 64 columns.
It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAn2C.png)
I need to make like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elVcd.png)

I've tried to use proc transpose, but I felt.
Please help.

Comment: Show the code you ran and explain how it failed.  Does the value of DATE uniquely identify a row in the original dateset?  That is are there 337 distinct values of DATE?  If not then please describe what does uniquely identify a row.  If you just have DATE as the one id variable then you should expect to get 337*63 observations in the output dataset with variables DATE, \_NAME_ and COL1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to `TRANSPOSE` `BY DATE` and then **`SORT`** `by country date`, I presume country is from the **label** of the original variables.

Example:
3 dates and 5 variables, easily changed for larger data.

```
data total_returns(label='Example data');
  do date = '01jan2020'd to '03jan2020'd;
    array RI RI_1-RI_5;
    do over ri;
      demo_value + 1;
      RI = demo_value;
    end;
    output;
  end;
  label
    RI_1 = 'MSCI Country Biff blah blah blah'
    RI_2 = 'MSCI Country Bam blah blah blah'
    RI_3 = 'MSCI Country Boom blah blah blah'
    RI_4 = 'MSCI Country Zwok blah blah blah'
    RI_5 = 'MSCI Country Pow blah blah blah'
  ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
  drop demo_value;
run;

proc transpose 
  data=total_returns 
  out=stage1 ( 
    drop=_name_ 
    rename= ( _label_=Country  
              col1 = RI
            ) 
  )
;
  by date;
  var RI_1-RI_5;
  label country = ' ';
run;

proc sort data=stage1 out=want;
  by country date;
run;

proc print label data=total_returns;
  title "Original, across/array layout";
proc print data=want;
  title "Transposed and Sorted, categorical/vector layout";
run;
```

Output:
[image]